# Mutate with ifelse condition group_by ID

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I would like to know how to create a new column with conditionals values.

I have a dataframe called 'df' with 4 columns : ID of the person , Question, title of the question, and Answer . I would like to add a column 'TEST' depending on the answer given by the persons (ID) .

For example : If a person answered 'No' to the question 1 'Do you have kids' , 'No' to  question 2 'Have you ever been married', and 'NO' to the question 3' Did you went to college' the value asigned to the column 'TEST' should be 'A' . But if he ansewerd 'No' to question 1 ,'Yes'to question 2 and 'Yes' to question 3 the value asigned to column test should be 'B'.

I was hoping to find a solution to my problem using the dplyr package for creating a new column 'TEST' :

Here is my code, but it do not work  :

```
  df  %>%  
  group_by(ID) %>%  
  mutate(TEST = ifelse (   (Question == '1' & Answer == "No") & (Question == '2' & Answer == "No") & (Question == '3' & Answer == "No") , 'A'
                           ifelse ( (Question == '1' & Answer == "No") & (Question == '2' & Answer == "Yes") & (Question == '3' & Answer == "Yes") , 'B' 
                                    ifelse (  (Question == '1' & Answer == "Yes") & (Question == '2' & Answer == "Yes") & (Question == '3' & Answer == "No") , 'C'   
                                              ifelse( (Question == '1' & Answer == "Yes") & (Question == '2' & Answer == "No") & (Question == '3' & Answer == "No") , 'D' )
                                    )))
```

The result of the code I am looking for should have this result in this particular example::
[image]

Does anyone have an idea about how to do this in dplyr? This data frame is just an example, the data frames I am dealing with are much larger. Because of its speed I tried to use dplyr, but perhaps there are other, better ways to handle this problem?

Comment: For a chained `if_else`, try using `case_when()`

Comment: You are using a mix of `=` and `==`. When doing a test, you always need `==`/ All of your `Question =` need to be changed to `Question ==`. Taking TTS's advice and switching to `case_when` will make your code much more readable too.

Comment: However, your long format data makes this awkward--you can never have `Question == '1'` and `Question == '2'` both true in the same row. You either need to convert your data to wide format with 1 question per column or use a construction like `Answer[Question == '1'] == 'No' & Answer[Question == '2'] == 'Yes'`, etc.

Comment: If you need more help than those comments, please share data reproducibly as copy/pasteable text. We can't test or debug code on a picture. `dput(df[1:12, ])` will create a copy/pasteable version of the first 12 rows of `df`, which is ideal for sharing.

Comment: Not sure if this is a typo, but your first three rows look to be grouped together but they are not the same `ID`.

Comment: @GregorThomas i tried to use the contruction that you proposed as 'Answer[Question == '1'] == 'No' & Answer[Question == '2'] == 'Yes' ' , but i got this error message : ' Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `TEST = ifelse(...)`.
✖ `constat` must be size 74102 or 1, not 0.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: @LMCT I'll repeat my last comment. *If you need more help than those comments, please share data reproducibly as copy/pasteable text. We can't test or debug code on a picture. `dput(df[1:12, ])` will create a copy/pasteable version of the first 12 rows of `df`, which is ideal for sharing.* If you share some data in a way I can use it, then I can test code, see errors and fix them. Having you run code (that I can't see all of) on data that I only have a picture of, and having you then report back the error message... is not a good way to solve a problem.

Answer (score 1):

`case_when()` allows for easy chaining of `if_else()` statements

The way your data is currently structured doesn't cleanly work with the approach you're trying to take so I suggest pivoting it wider (using `pivot_wider`) to make it easier to work with.

Here's an example of that workflow.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(ID = "ID",
             Question = c("Q1","Q2","Q3"),
             Answer = c("Yes", "No", "Yes"))


df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Question, values_from = Answer) %>% 
  mutate(TEST = case_when(Q1 == "Yes" & Q2 == "Yes" & Q3 == "Yes" ~ "A",
                          Q1 == "Yes" & Q2 == "Yes" & Q3 == "No"  ~ "B",
                          Q1 == "Yes" & Q2 == "No"  & Q3 == "Yes" ~ "C",
                          Q1 == "Yes" & Q2 == "No"  & Q3 == "No"  ~ "D",
                          Q1 == "No"  & Q2 == "Yes" & Q3 == "Yes" ~ "E",
                          Q1 == "No"  & Q2 == "Yes" & Q3 == "No"  ~ "F",
                          Q1 == "No"  & Q2 == "No"  & Q3 == "Yes" ~ "G",
                          Q1 == "No"  & Q2 == "No"  & Q3 == "No"  ~ "H"))

# # A tibble: 1 × 5
#   ID    Q1    Q2    Q3    TEST 
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 ID    Yes   No    Yes   C
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest an alternative method to `case_when` is to left-join to the pivoted data. While it will effect the same result, it may be easier to read and/or maintain.

```r
ref <- tibble::tribble(
    ~Q1  , ~Q2  , ~Q3  , ~TEST
  , "No" , "No" , "No" , "A"  
  , "No" , "Yes", "Yes", "B"  
  , "Yes", "Yes", "No" , "C"  
  , "Yes", "No" , "No" , "D"  
)
```

Using `ref` above may be easier to maintain, as it can be edited in any table-editing format (Excel, Calc, text editor, etc). While not difficult, editing a `case_when` can be prone to a few more typos and/or mistakes.

From here,

```r
out <- df %>%
  select(ID, Question, Answer) %>% # we don't need title, or others
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = Question, values_from = Answer) %>%
  left_join(ref, by = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3"))
out
# # A tibble: 2 x 5
#   ID     Q1    Q2    Q3    TEST 
#   <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 AB2Z12 No    No    No    A    
# 2 ZZDA45 No    Yes   Yes   B
```

Note that combinations not present (e.g., `"No", "Yes", "No"`) will produce `TEST = NA`. This can be dealt with in other ways, either by explicitly covering all 8 permutations with `TEST` values, or by replacing `NA` later with something else.

To bring this back to the original data, we can join this back on `df`:

```r
left_join(df, out, by = "ID")
# # A tibble: 6 x 8
#   ID     Question title    Answer Q1    Q2    Q3    TEST 
#   <chr>  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 AB2Z12 Q1       kids?    No     No    No    No    A    
# 2 AB2Z12 Q2       married? No     No    No    No    A    
# 3 AB2Z12 Q3       college? No     No    No    No    A    
# 4 ZZDA45 Q1       kids?    No     No    Yes   Yes   B    
# 5 ZZDA45 Q2       married? Yes    No    Yes   Yes   B    
# 6 ZZDA45 Q3       college? Yes    No    Yes   Yes   B
```

---

Data

```r
df <- structure(list(ID = c("AB2Z12", "AB2Z12", "AB2Z12", "ZZDA45", "ZZDA45", "ZZDA45"), Question = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3"), title = c("kids?", "married?", "college?", "kids?", "married?", "college?"), Answer = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```